# Find and delete row formula

Tags: google-sheets, row, move

I have a Google sheet with inventory on it. Every time I sell something I currently have to search up the SKU (with search and replace) and manually delete the row for each product sold. I was wondering if there was a way to scan (or type in) my SKU and automatically delete a row (moving the row to another sheet would work also). Is this possible?

Comment: Good practice would be, maintain a master data entry sheet. Then use different formula in other sheet to see your desired report.

Comment: `and manually delete the row for each product sold` Further to @Harun24hr, another option would be to include a field (maybe a checkbox) for "sold" and filter the data on that sheet for all rows where checkbox <>true.

Comment: `Every time I sell something I currently have to search up the SKU` Have you tried using a dropdown to filter the records; put a field for the SKU above the records, enter the SKU so that only records with that SKU are displayed.